# Spring+Quartz Fire job execution only if previous has finished

Tags: spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I'm using SpringMVC (4.x) along with Quartz (2.x). I'm setting a bean defnition file to fire a simple job, but wnat to make sure that the job is only fired if the previous execution of that job has already finished. Is there a parameter I can inform to `SimpleTriggerFactoryBean` in order to avoid concurrent execution?

By using the `repeatInterval` property, won't I fire simultaneous jobs?

#### My Quartz Bean Definition XML

```
<bean id="autoPusherJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="br.teste.AutoMessagePusherJob" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="userName" value="SystemCronJob"/>
            <entry key="message">
                <bean class ="br.teste.model.Message"/>
            </entry>            
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="durability" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="simpleTrigger"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="autoPusherJob" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="1000" />
</bean>


<bean  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="autoPusherJob" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your job class needs to be annotated with the [DisallowConcurrentExecution](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.html) annotation.

Comment: Isn't that annotation supposed to be only used with classes extending/implementing `JobDetail` as says de javadoc? (>where instance is based-upon a JobDetail definition)

Comment: Yes, you will need to annotate your br.teste.AutoMessagePusherJob class. There is no job/trigger property you can use to achive what you want. However, what you can do if you, for whaever reason, cannot modify the AutoMessagePusherJob class is that you subclass it, annotate your subclass and use the subclass in the Spring config.